# Surface plot with irregular grid

Tags: matlab

I'd like to plot some data in 3D similar to that produced from:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

But with one difference. The isolines that appear on the above surface plot are deformed such that they "stretch" to match the changes in the Z axis. Does anyone know how to produce a surface plot but with the isolines appearing as though a regularly spaced grid has been "draped" over the surface? I'm assuming the grids specifying the data will no longer be monotonically spaced but I'm unsure about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)?
Take a closer look at the first example there: "Interpolate Scattered Data Over a Uniform Grid".